# Accessing ints from another class

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have another view that handles the score from the last sessions as well as leaderboards. How can I access my score int from the GameScene class in my GameOver class?

With out looking much I tried to find the way myself by doing this:

```
class GameOver: SKScene {

let score = GameScene().score

init(size: CGSize, won:Bool) {

    super.init(size: size)

    backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    var message = "\(score)"

    println(score)

    let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AvenirNextCondensed-Heavy")
    label.text = message
    label.fontSize = 40
    label.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    label.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    addChild(label)
}
```

I thought that if I created a variable for my score in GameScene it would work, and it does however it uses the score variable that is equal to 0. So how would I transfer the score from when the player dies to the scene above?

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None: UInt32 = 0
    static let All: UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let Enemy: UInt32 = 0b1
    static let Player: UInt32 = 0b10
}

let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player")
var playerAlive: Bool = true

var touched:Bool = false
var location = CGPointMake(0, 0)

var difficulty = 1.0

var timer: NSTimer!
var scoreTimer: NSTimer!
var lastAddedTime : CFTimeInterval = 0

var score: Int = 0
var scoreLabel: SKLabelNode!


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    player.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.25)
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: player.size.width/2)
    player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
    player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    player.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    addChild(player)

    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "increaseDifficulty", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    var scoreTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "addScore", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AvenirNextCondensed-Heavy")
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    scoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 40
    scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + self.frame.size.height * 0.4)
    addChild(scoreLabel)

}

func addScore() {
    score += 1
    println(score)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare score variable as class level variable but it is not directly supported in Swift so wrap `score` var in struct like this:

```
private struct ScoreStruct { 
  static var score: Int = 0 
}

class var staticScore: Int {
   get { return ScoreStruct.score }
   set { ScoreStruct.score = newValue }
}
```

And you can use it like: `GameScene.staticScore`

Comment: Just a quick question. Would this be needed in my GameScene or GameOver? @aks

Comment: if you are modifying score var in GameScene then declare this struct in GameScene & you can change its value directly like   'staticScore++' in GameScene class. & use it in GameOver class using 'GameScene.staticScore'

Answer (score 0):

GameScene is a class. Where is it instantiated?
Search your project for the term "presentScene:" there should be some language like

```
let myGameScene = GameScene()
skView.presentScene(myGameScene)
```

Also there must be a place in your project contains code like the following. Add the line with the comment

```
let myGameOver = GameOverScene()
if(conditionIsMet)
{
    myGameOver.passScore(myGameScene.score) //add this line
    skView.presentScene(myGameOver)
}
```